# How to enable django admin sidebar navigation in a custom view?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a view inheriting from `LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView`, which renders some data using the `admin/base_site.html` template as the base. I treat it as a part of the admin interface, so it requires an administrator login. I'd like to make this view a little bit more a part of the Django admin interface by enabling the standard sidebar navigation on the left-hand side.

Note that I don't have a custom `ModelAdmin` definition anywhere, I simply render the template at some predefined URL. There are no models used in the interface either, it parses and displays data from database-unrelated sources.

Currently, I just build the required context data manually, e.g.:

```py
data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
data.update(**{
    "is_popup": False,
    "site_header": None,
    "is_nav_sidebar_enabled": True,
    "has_permission": True,
    "title": "My title",
    "subtitle": None,
    "site_url": None,
    "available_apps": []
})
```

The sidebar is visible, but displays an error message:

[image: Error message: You don't have permission to view or edit anything]

Adding an app to `available_apps` (`"available_apps": ["my_app"]`) doesn't help either:

[image: Rendered sidebar with no data]

So my question is - how do I do that? Is there a class I can inherit from to achieve this behaviour? Or a method I can call to get all required context data for `base_site.html`? Or perhaps I should insert some information in my template? Perhaps I need an `AdminSite` object, or can somehow call methods of the default one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By accident I noticed there is a `DefaultAdminSite` object in `django.contrib.admin.sites`, and it's instantiated as `site`. Therefore, in my case, simply using `site` is sufficient.

```py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.contrib.admin.sites import site
admin_site: AdminSite = site
data.update(**admin_site.each_context(self.request))
```

Furthermore, turns out I can just use the `apps` in case importing `site` would be an issue, just like `DefaultAdminSite` does it:

```py
AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config("admin").default_site)
self._wrapped = AdminSiteClass()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include django admin's default context variables used in the template. This can be done by calling [`each_context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.each_context) function:

```py
data.update(self.admin_site.each_context(request))
```

I also have custom admin views and templates in my projects and this works well for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This won't work because the class doesn't have the `admin_site` attribute. What classes do you inherit from?

Comment: @KacperFloriański Django's `admin.ModelAdmin` class. Now, I read your question again and realised you're not inheriting from it. Sorry about that. But I see you've found an answer so that's great.

Answer (score 1):

The [`app_list.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0.4/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/app_list.html) template which is included in your base template requires a context variable `available_apps` with a structure as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.each_context).

As you probably won't be able to make this include work properly with your app you could also override the `{% block nav-sidebar %}` in your base template and provide some HTML that fits your use-case.

But after all it's probably not such a good idea to reuse templates which are made for a different app (admin) with your app because it's difficult to predict how they will behave, what their requirements are and beyond this maintainance in the long term will also be a problem as they might change with future Django versions.